# Gatsby link sharing issue

Tags: gatsby, mobile-safari

I'm experiencing odd behaviour when sharing links to my Gatsby website from Safari.

When I share a link to a blog on my Gatsby website on safari, it adds /undefined/[duplicate of slug]

eg. On this page - https://www.tasafaris.com/blog/exploring-cape-town-unique-hotel-experiences/ When I share the link to Whatsapp, it shares as https://www.tasafaris.com/blog/exploring-cape-town-unique-hotel-experiences/undefined/blog/exploring-cape-town-unique-hotel-experiences/

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?